# Difference between interior and exterior headers

Tags: doors, beam

This appears to be a great site for calculating header and beam requirements:
http://learnframing.com/wood-beam-calculator/
But it distinguishes between interior and exterior beams -- and the results are very different. 
I am adding an addition to my one-story house. I am knocking a 10' wide door between the existing building and the addition. This door is going into the existing "exterior" wall. But when things are finished it will be in an "interior" wall. I have calculated the weight, and added the weight of the new roof to the existing. But I can't understand the tool's differences for interior vs exterior and hence not sure which to use.

Comment: Seems to me after reconstruction on the exterior wall would be defined as an interior  wall while the new external header carries the new external load of the roof and 2nd floor

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as “bearing” and “non-bearing” walls.

Although, when I tested the beam calculator out, it is not accurate. It’s very conservative...especially the end bearing requirements.

Comment: Of course it's "very conservative" - it's a general purpose tool put on the internet for the not-trained, general public to use. I consider myself reasonably intelligent and am reasonably well educated, but would probably do a horrible job at estimating the weights necessary. They're covering their butts (and possibly saving lives) by being "very conservative". ;)